Modal draw over other apps | React Native
I'm trying to make a learning application where a puzzle appears everytime the user clicks tries to access Youtube and doesn't allow the user to access it unless the puzzle is done correctly, my question is if there is a way that allows a screen or a modal from react native to draw over other apps, and to be set by a trigger (Accessing Youtube)? Thanks in advance.
I've tried using floating buttons and floating modals but it did not work.

you can use the react-native-webview to show the webpage you want inside you're app: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview
